# ffmpeg Duplicating Frames

Tags: video, ffmpeg, framerate, mpeg2

A very annoying situation...
 
I have an MPG2 video that is at the framerate of 29.97, yet when converting to MP4 frames are duplicated.

That command (straight conversion, no options):
    `ffmpeg -i ~/Desktop/file.mpg ~/Desktop/file.mp4`
causes duplicated frames...
While setting the framerate with:
    `ffmpeg -i ~/Desktop/file.mpg -framerate 29.97 ~/Desktop/file.mp4`
 Doesn't work either!
Leading me to try:
    `ffmpeg -i ~/Desktop/file.mpg -r 29.97 ~/Desktop/file.mp4`
Still with duplicated frames!
Finally I tried ffmpeg's **3rd** framerate option!:
    `ffmpeg -i ~/Desktop/file.mpg -vf fps=fps=29.97 ~/Desktop/file.mp4`

Except, when it outputted, the audio/video was out of sync!

Which FPS option should I use?

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i ~/Desktop/file.mpg -vsync 0 ~/Desktop/file.mp4
```

This skips duplication.

`-vsync passthrough` is synonymous with `-vsync 0`.

Comment: This sounds like it might work, but I get innumerable errors!

Comment: DTS errors? You can ignore those if the file plays correctly. Show the full log.

Comment: where `-vsync 0` is the same as the newer value `-vsync passthrough`. Each frame is passed with its timestamp from the demuxer to the muxer.

Comment: @l--marcl you should post this answer. this was *exactly* what I needed. I have a filtergraph that creates an intro video with an image input on a solid color bg (all through filters) and concats it to my video. everything seemed fine, but it outputted all duped frames. Now the problem is solved!

Answer (score 1):

`-vsync` is deprecated now, so you should use `-fps_mode` instead.

By default, the `fps_mode` is `auto`, so it may change your fps automatically. For example, the original source is variable frame rate, but ffmpeg may decide to change it to constant frame rate automatically, which may result in duplicated and dropped frames.

To prevent any fps change, set `-fps_mode passthrough`. (It's the same as `-vsync 0` or `-vsync passthrough`).

For more info, see [ffmpeg documentation](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html).

```
ffmpeg -i ~/Desktop/file.mpg -fps_mode passthrough ~/Desktop/file.mp4
```